# Correct way to implement search on a recyclerview with firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to implement a search function on my recyclerviewer but I'm having some trouble with it. I have created the query and the method for it,but the search does not return anything at all.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

...
...
...

mDBListener = mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            mUploads.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Buildings upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Buildings.class);
                upload.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());
                mUploads.add(upload);

            }

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


    mButtonSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String searchText = mSearchView.getText().toString();
            firebaseUserSearch(searchText);
        }
    });
```

and i have this outside of my onCreate

```
private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {

    Query queryRef = mDatabaseRef.child("Buildings").orderByChild("name").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");
    queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {

                for (DataSnapshot postsSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    final Buildings buildings = postsSnapshot.getValue(Buildings.class);
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Is this the correct way to implement it?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the precise value of `searchText` that you're using. Also please show some of the JSON which you expect to be returned (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please provide what Frank van Puffelen asked for and please also responde with @.